# How to regex-pattern-match a variable-length word with a fixed prefix?

Tags: regex, sed, key-value

**Summary**

How does one regex pattern-match what I think might (?) be best described as a "variable-length word with a fixed prefix"?

**Details**

Examples below attempt to remove the `aa:22`. None of them work.

Preferred output for all commands is `bb:33 cc:44`. Granted, these commands are not designed to remove leading or extra spaces.

I employ `perl -pe` (unsuccessfully, in the first command) attempting to make the variable-length-pattern match be "non greedy."

In these examples, `aa:` is the prefix (can be thought of as the "key" in a key-value pair) and `22` is the variable-content, variable-length value; ie, it could be `aa:2vED/3rD@&x3J{ZB334}A` (in this syntax, any string containing non-whitespace characters other than a `:`), but it will always be right-side bordered with whitespace (space and tab are the only whitespace characters, yes?) or end-of-line.

Further: the word sequences (key-value pairs) can be find be found in any order. As such, `awk`-based fixed-column matches will presumably not work.

I'm seeking an elegant, simple solution. I've read numerous Stack Overflow answers whose regex's appear remarkably long and complex to the point they are unintelligible. Clearly I am not sufficiently regex educated.

sed, perl, awk, grep, or any other POSIX-oriented solutions are acceptable so long as the solution is minimally compatible with baseline macOS and Linux.

```
$ echo 'aa:22 bb:33 cc:44' | perl -pe 's|aa:.*\b||'

$ 
$ echo 'aa:22 bb:33 cc:44' | perl -pe 's|aa:.*?\b||'
22 bb:33 cc:44
$ 
$ echo 'aa:22 bb:33 cc:44' | perl -pe 's|aa:\B*\b||'
22 bb:33 cc:44
$ 
$ echo 'aa:22 bb:33 cc:44' | perl -pe 's|aa\B*\b||'
:22 bb:33 cc:44
$ 
$ echo 'aa:22 bb:33 cc:44' | perl -pe 's|aa:(?!.*)\b||'
aa:22 bb:33 cc:44
$ 
$ echo 'aa:22 bb:33 cc:44' | perl -pe 's|aa:(?!.*)*\b||'
22 bb:33 cc:44
$ 
$ echo 'aa:22 bb:33 cc:44' | perl -pe 's|aa:.*^(?!.*)||'
aa:22 bb:33 cc:44
$ 
$ echo 'reordering...'
reordering...
$ 
$ echo 'bb:33 aa:22 cc:44' | perl -pe 's|aa\B*\b||'
bb:33 :22 cc:44
$ 
$ 
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.6
BuildVersion:   18G1012
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo 'aa:22 bb:33 cc:44' | sed -E 's/aa:[^[:space:]:]*([[:space:]]|$)//'
bb:33 cc:44
$ echo 'bb:33 aa:22 cc:44' | sed -E 's/aa:[^[:space:]:]*([[:space:]]|$)//'
bb:33 cc:44
$ echo 'bb:33 cc:44 aa:22' | sed -E 's/aa:[^[:space:]:]*([[:space:]]|$)//'
bb:33 cc:44
```

- `-E` is for ERE support,
- `[^[:space:]:]*` matches 0+ any character but wspace and colon,
- and `([[:space:]]|$)` matches bordering wspace or EOL.

Comment: Is `( |$)` needed?

Comment: @PJProudhon isn't it?

Comment: Many thanks @oguzismail. The following derivation (`\s` replaces `[:space:]`) appears to work for all these examples:  `sed -E 's/aa:[^\s:]*(\s|$)//'`  Does it work in general?

Comment: I don't think so: `[^[:space:]:]*` will match every character which are not spacing or colon. When followed by a space, that one will then never be matched. When EOS is reached, there's simply nothing left to match.

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh I can't say yes. Neither -E, nor \s is portable. Most seds have -E but can't say the same for \s. If you want maximum portability, go with `sed 's/aa:[^[:space:]:]*\([[:space:]]\|$\)//'`; it should work with all POSIX-compliant seds

Comment: @PJProudhon I'm not following, can you elaborate?

Comment: @JohnnyUtahh `\s` and other such character sets don't work inside character class..  it would match ``\`` and `s` instead of whitespace... for example, `echo 'a\sb\cdsssssssssss12' | sed 's/[\s]*//g'` will give `abcd12`

Comment: Super helpful, thanks all. And in the case where `:` is an accepted character in the "value" of the key-value pair, does the following (removing the `:` in the negative match) work in general?  `sed -E 's/aa:[^[:space:]]*([[:space:]]|$)//'`

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
echo 'aa:22 bb:33 cc:44' | sed -r 's/aa:[^ ]+ //g'
bb:33 cc:44
```

It looks for `aa` and and all other character up to first space.

Comment: It does not work in this case: `$ echo 'bb:33 cc:44 aa:22' | sed -r 's/aa:[^ ]+ //g'` --> `bb:33 cc:44 aa:22`. Remove the last space and it works... but leaves the extra "double space" in the cases where `aa:22` is not at the end of the line. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: Also, with the `[^ ]` (space only), this may not work for a tab-delimited string.